# Error RunBuild CircleCI "Disabling ANDROID_TEST_USES_UNIFIED_TEST_PLATFORM" option because this is a dynamic-feature module

Tags: circleci

i got some error when integrated my project with CircleCI. The error in RunBuild process and the message error like the picture below

[RunBuild Error in CircleCI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVXaK.png)

I haven't found a solution yet, can you guys help me?

Comment: Does this is an Android gradle error happen when you build on your machine?